# Is there a container format in ffmpeg that supports non-monotonous timestamps?

Tags: ffmpeg, file-formats, sync, timecode

I have recorded over-the-air digital TV broadcasts from my own antenna.  Due to reception blips, the MPEG-TS file can have corrupted packets, and thus corrupted timestamps, in the middle of a recording.  These timestamp problems cause A/V de-synchronization during transcoding, even with -async and -vsync flags.  -fflags +discardcorrupt gets rid of some of the corrupted timestamps, but not all of them.

I've poured a LOT of effort into trying to fix these recordings such that A/V de-synchronization doesn't happen.  I've developed several methods that work to varying degrees of satisfaction, but I'm still looking to develop a better way.

This is what I want to do: I want to use ffmpeg -fflags +discardcorrupt and -codec copy to copy streams that completely preserves timestamps, even non-monotonous timestamps, so that I can later develop methods to further correct the timestamps.  Essentially, I want to take advantage of +discardcorrupt, but preserve the remaining bad timestamps so I can go back later and deal with it.

So here's my question:
**Is there a container format, possibly coupled with ffmpeg options, I can use where I can copy A/V streams such that non-monotonous timestamps are completely preserved, where ffmpeg doesn't try to fix/guess PTS/DTS values?**

Comment: This is not directly possible. All muxers require monotonic TS. At best, a few allow non-decreasing TS. However, there may be a way to achieve this in a roundabout way. Let me check.

Comment: Have you tried the +nofillin value for -fflags? That *may* fix your issue.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49556376/4675388